Why is my mouse cursor so big on WSL2 applications?
I did a do-release-upgrade in my WSL2 setup today to go to Ubuntu 24.04 and now my mouse cursor when I hover over graphical Linux applications is huge. It's probably 4 times as tall and 4 times as wide as it should be.
>wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-24.04 (Default)

>wsl --version
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3880

I don't really understand which piece of software is responsible for drawing these cursors, so I'm not sure which setting I should tweak. Interestingly as I move my mouse from the Windows desktop to the window decoration (containing minimize, maximize and close buttons), the cursor changes from the standard windows white with black outline to a more rounded grey cursor with a black outline and then when I get to the body of the window it changes into the huge cursor which is black with a white outline.
I have also opened a github issue against the microsoft/WSL repository

usually thats a scaling issue.  I have the same problem with certain linux apps.

All of my displays are at native resolution (1920x1080 or 1920x1200) with scale set to 100%.

"I don't really understand which piece of software is responsible for drawing these cursors" - WSLg.  However, you are not running the current Linux kernel. So you might want to update it.  You are running the current version of WSLg. Any information that is important enough to share in a comment should be an [edit] to your question. You might have to upgrade to 23H2 to resolve this problem. You are currently running Windows 10 22H2 which isn't supported. I am not saying the fact you are running 22H2 is the reason, WSLg is misbehaving, but it cannot be ruled out

You can try and update the WSL Linux kernel by running wsl --update but you might have to download the current release and run the installer. As I hinted you might have to update from 22H2 to 23H2 for even that to be possible.

Same issue after updating to 24.04. Adding gtk-cursor-theme-size=24 to these files helped me:
~/.gtkrc-2.0
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini

Both github-desktop and gedit, I was checking with, use gtk-3.0 - so might be enough to modify only ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini.

I edited all of the files that you mentioned to add gtk-cursor-theme-size=24 within a [Settings] section and rebooted my PC. The cursors are still large after the reboot when I launch konsole or emacs, but I tried a gtk application and it has normal sized mouse cursors.
